# How to compare the screen to a screenshot in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-3.8

I'm making a Python program that opens [Target](https://www.target.com) and buys an item entered by the user. If the item is unavailable, the program does nothing and prints a message in the console. To check if the item is available, I need to check if the screen includes something similar to a screenshot I took. The screenshot is shown below.
[image: [Screenshot][1]]

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you sure can compare two screenshots, using library as matplotlib, PIL or opencv (or even numpy) but I guess the easiest path is to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) (if you automate your navigation) or beautifulsoup4/scrapy.

Something like :

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.target.com/"
browser.get(url)

# navigate to find your product
out_of_stock_text = "put your stuff here"
if out_of_stock_text in browsers.page_source:
   # Do your stuff here
```

Good luck !

Comment: Would I set the value of `out-of-stock-text` to the image path, text to search for on the page, or something else? Sorry, I've never used Selenium before.

Comment: As a text, selenium or scrapers search within the source of the displayed page. I guess Selenium is what you need, because afterwards you will have to fill search bar, click buttons etc... You will find great tutorials on the net, this is how I learn to use it. Happy coding !